# Create a series of mappings through for loop and exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.20.1 and Python 3.6.
First please check my example:
Say I have a dataframe named *a*:

```
  up  down
0  a  high
1  a   low
2  b   low
3  c  high
```

Each column has some strings. What I want to do is transforming those strings into digits, and also store mappings for each column in a dataframe.
That is:

```
  up down
0  0    0
1  0    1
2  1    1
3  2    0
```

and store the mappings in two dataframes named in the format of *column_name + '_code'*.In my example, they are *up_code* and *down_code*:

```
  up  up_id
0  a      0
1  b      1
2  c      2

  down  down_id
0 high        0
1  low        1
```

What I have tried is:

```
cols = ['up', 'down']
for col in cols:
    exec("%(k)s_code = pd.DataFrame({%(k)s:a[col].unique(), %(k)s_id:range(len(a[col].unique()))})" % {'k':col})
```

I expected this would create the dataframes storing mappings but it raised a name error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-7fc8a22fc7f1>", line 2, in <module>
    exec("%(k)s_code = pd.DataFrame({%(k)s:a[col].unique(), %(k)s_id:range(len(a[col].unique()))})" % {'k':col})

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'up' is not defined
```

What have I done wrong here? Or is there a more simple way to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dict's keys must be strings,numbers or variabels with something assigned to it. In your case when you use exec method variables are created so  change your code `(k)s` and `(k)s_id` to  `'(k)s'` and `'(k)s_id'` .

```
cols = ['up', 'down']
for col in cols:
    exec("%(k)s_code = pd.DataFrame({'%(k)s':a[col].unique(), '%(k)s_id':range(len(a[col].unique()))})" % {'k':col})
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward! Thank you Bharath!

Comment: Glad to help Sean